# use material-calendarview in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewbinding

I am trying to use the [material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) in my compose project by the means of `AndroidViewBinding`.

The code is straighforward:

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:mcv_tileHeight="match_parent"
    app:mcv_tileWidth="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the composable:

```
@Composable
fun MaterialCalendarView() {
    val color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface.toArgb()
    AndroidViewBinding(CalendarViewBinding::inflate) {
        calendar.setBackgroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting some weird exception:

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 430032 byte allocation with 297064 free bytes and 290KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592" (VmSize 33280556 kB, recursive case)
```